# Unit test SparseArray using JUnit (using JVM)

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit

I have an implementation which is using a Integer as key in HashMap. It is already unit tested using JUnit. But I want to change it to SparseArray which is more optimised version from Android. I am not sure how will it be unit tested using JUnit. Does anyone have a better way to do this?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There's an equivalent implementation of SparseArray in Support Library called [SparseArrayCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/util/SparseArrayCompat.html) that can be used in JVM Unit Tests. Also it has more features than the native one, so you're better off using that.

Answer (score 10):

In case anyone is still looking, you don't need any third party libraries. You can simply mock SparseArray.

Create a file SparseArray.java inside app/src/test/java/android/util and paste the following:

```
package android.util;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class SparseArray<E> {

    private HashMap<Integer, E> mHashMap;

    public SparseArray() {
        mHashMap = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void put(int key, E value) {
        mHashMap.put(key, value);
    }

    public E get(int key) {
        return mHashMap.get(key);
    }
}
```

**Note**: In case you are using funcations beside `put` and `get` you will need to implement those here as well.

Answer (score 6):

Unmock is a really nice project that gives you this and more. https://github.com/bjoernQ/unmock-plugin

Just add the plugin and it will work.

Comment: @Amit As time goes by I would agree that [rakshakhegde's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46387176/356895) is now the better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Configuring tests with [roboelectric](http://robolectric.org/) framework may be simpler.

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner;

@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class XxxTest {
    ...
}
```